# How to change the background of a ScrollPane (JavaFX/ScalaFX)?

Tags: scala, javafx, background-color, scalafx

I want to change the background color of a ScrollPane. This is part of my code where I try to do that:

```
    val sp=new javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane(new Group(new Text(...)))
    sp.setPannable(true)
    sp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue")
    sp.setBackground(new Background(Array(new BackgroundFill(Color.DARKCYAN,new CornerRadii(0),Insets(0)))))
```

Text appears OK, but both attempts to change the background color have no effect, using:
*Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).*

Inspecting with [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/), I discover that two StackPanes have unexpectedly appeared in the scene graph below the ScrollPane, so the hierarchy is:

1. ScrollPane //which I created
2. StackPane //UNEXPECTED -- clips the content
3. StackPane //UNEXPECTED -- full size content
4. Group //which I created
5. Text //which I created

If I change the background of either of the StackPane-s to, say, `"-fx-background-color: blue"` (with [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)), it has effect, but not the style of the ScrollPane. But how to do that from code? If I do

```
println(sp.content())
```

, it says

> Group@567fa81a

Is there a simple way to access the StackPanes or change the background? I could "slap in" a big filled rectangle, but that seems ugly and complicates resizing, what is wrong with the background proper?

Comment: Can you post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sp.setStyle("-fx-background: blue")
```

instead of:

```
sp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue")
```

Comment: "fx-background-color" is for the boarder around the stackpane.

Comment: color with transparency does not work with this method

Answer (score 2):

Similar to `JScrollPane`, JavaFX `ScrollPane` has a `StackPane` container within itself called `viewport`. So to set background for your `ScrollPane` use this CSS rule (i.e. to set red background color):

```
.scroll-pane .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Branislab Lazic thanks bro! i was searching this answer for a long time!